# how can I get rid of the extra tablet features windows 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-tablet

I have a pen-tablet, and under XP it simply connected and worked in apps. 
now in windows 7, it starts up 4+ extra programs to adapt to being used as a tablet PC- except that the computer is not a tablet PC,it's a desktop with a basic tablet plugged into it. is it possible to make windows stop loading up all these extra features when they are not needed?

Comment: @techie007 Although the question is similar, in this case the OP has a desktop PC, and not a tablet PC.

Comment: To me it's the same question. The root of the question is "How do I turn off the Windows 7 tablet features", and the linked question has that answered many times over, even if it wasn't specific to the model in the question. But hey, it takes 5 votes to close. ;)

Comment: I don't want to disable the ability to use tablets completely, I just want to get rid of all the extra processes since the device has it's own driver that works well. it seems kind of silly for MS to assume the computer is a tablet-PC just because touch input was introduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type or paste `OptionalFeatures.exe` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Uncheck the **Tablet PC Components** option from the list, and click **OK**.
3. Restart Windows to apply the changes.